# It is possible to run the simulated omni-wheel robot without plugins

Tags: ros, gazebo, urdf, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I am wondering if it is possible to simulate an omni-wheel robot without moving it with the [gazebo plugin (Planar Move Plugin)](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_gzplugins#PluginTypes), If so, can someone help me make it?
I would appreciate it, thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/364481/it-is-possible-to-run-the-simulated-omni-wheel-robot-without-plugins/) by [al_ca](https://answers.ros.org/users/55624/al_ca/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2020-10-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

yes you can if you thing of normal wheels, but with mecanum \ onmi wheels it get to complicaten with all the roller and and friction so you resould would not be better then the planar mover.

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2020-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [al_ca](https://answers.ros.org/users/55624/al_ca/) on 2020-11-02**:
In my case, I want to build my robot in a simulation in order to test there some things, not in the real one but to have almost the same results as if I did it in the real one... it is achievable or it isn't worth it?

**Comment by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) on 2020-11-03**:
what kind of kinematic do like to use? if you have somethin like http://www.karispro.de/ then it schould work if you have some think like this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rIiF0I7LT-g you will not have bennefits compared to the planar mover.

**Comment by [al_ca](https://answers.ros.org/users/55624/al_ca/) on 2020-11-03**:
It's something like [this](https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/locomotion/#turtlebot3-friends-omni)

**Comment by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) on 2020-11-03**:
if it is the 3 sweden wheel then it is in the same class as mecanum and you can use the planar mover.
you can look at the https://github.com/GuiRitter/OpenBase may it helps.

**Comment by [al_ca](https://answers.ros.org/users/55624/al_ca/) on 2020-11-03**:
Basically, I am trying to do  the same as he does from around two weeks ago and it's difficult to implement it, and many problems in the movement were appearing.. maybe I am doing something wrong idk because I am relatively new to this environment. Nevertheless, I will move on with the planar move plugin so thank you for the time and help! If you want something to add, I am waiting.